# Have ispell ignore certain LaTeX tags

Tags: spelling

Using `ispell -t` on a `.tex` file generally does a good job of figuring out what is TeX and what isn't but it seems to find misspellings on commands that are generally going to be misspelled, i.e.

```
\includegraphics{myfig.jpg}
```

Gives a typo since `myfig` nor `.jpg` are in the dictionary. I think it would be silly to add them for every case. Is there a way to get ispell to ignore whatever is in a set of tags that I define?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of ispell look for the environment variable TEXSKIP1, which is assumed to contain a list of commands, each of which is assumed to take 1 argument, for which the argument should not be spell checked.  For example, my .bashrc file contains the line

export TEXSKIP1="+eqref,thmref,propref,corref,lemref,exref,notref,remref,defref,
diagref,chapref,secref,bibliography"

since I have, e.g., a command named `\thmref`, which expands to `Theorem~\ref`.

Note: Many linux systems give you aspell by default, to which they alias the ispell command.  If you're running actual ispell (I installed ispell-3.2.06-4asp.src.rpm), then you can use TEXSKIP1 and the analogous TEXSKIP2 for commands that take 2 arguments, neither of which should be spell checked.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to your question, but [aspell seems to be able to do what you want](http://aspell.net/man-html/Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes.html).